# Can a non-commutative operator for nested templated class inside a templated class be defined?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have this code:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{  
  public:
  template<typename innerT>
  class B
  {
  };
};
```

And I want to declare the "==" operator on A<T>::B<innerT> and "int" so that it returns different things based on whether the integer comes first or second.

The testing method would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 A<float>::B<double> b;
 std::cout << (b == 2) << " is different from " << (2 == b);
}
```

I was thinking of something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename innerT> bool operator==(typename A<T>::B<innerT> & one, int two)
{ return true; }

template<typename T,typename innerT> bool operator==(int one, typename A<T>::B<innerT> & two)
{ return false; }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem here is that `T` is a non-deduced context.

Comment: Even if remark of @jrok would not be fair a construction with `template` keyword should be used in such context: `typename A<T>::template B<innerT>`. And const reference is more preferable in comparison operators.

Answer (score 2):

You can move them into class `A` as friends:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{  
public:
  template<typename innerT>
  class B
  {
  };

  template<typename innerT>
  friend bool operator==(A::B<innerT> & one, int two)
  { return true; }

  template<typename innerT>
  friend bool operator==(int one, A::B<innerT> & two)
  { return false; }
};
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8bd0041bbc81ebb)

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work. However, in Visual Studio for it to compile, I have to add "typename" before "A::B<innerT> &" in parameters for it compile. But when I do this in the live example (compiled under g++), that gives me this error: 'typename A<T>::B' names 'template<class T> template<class innerT> class A<T>::B', which is not a type. Any idea why that is so?

Comment: @PetrHudeček That looks like a bug in VS to me, I'm pretty sure GCC (and Clang which agrees with GCC on this) are correct here.